# Can plugins see your passwords if you don't save them to the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, passwords, plugins, userscripts

I have a few plugins installed in google chrome, but I almost never save my passwords to google chrome. I almost always type them in every time. Can plugins only see your passwords if you type them in and then save them to the browser while they're on?

The only password I have saved to google chrome is my gmail, but I typed in my password while the plugins were off. In that case, it's saved to the browser, but it wasn't typed in while the plugins were on. In that case, can the plugins still see my password?

Comment: Yes, plugins and extensions can see and get your passwords and even send them back to some server.  It's one reason why Firefox and Chrome try to vet all extensions and limit what you can install outside their "stores".  Also, many an extension will record every webpage you visit.

Comment: An example: https://www.designitsolutions.com/2018/09/18/another-chrome-extension-is-stealing-passwords/

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it possible, malicious uses have been documented.  See this [article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-chrome-beware-these-malicious-extensions-that-record-everything-you-do/).  Always assume an extension can see everything you are doing, because as of right now, they can.

Do not use plugins from sources you do not trust.

Comment: But if it's in the google store it can be trusted? Or like what?